# Modalpopupextender gets hide for some time once checkchanged event fires?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used ModalpopupExtender control in my web page. I have checkbox for selectall option with checkchanged event with checkboxlist control(With list of options). Whenever i check selectall option then all rest of the options gets selected & modalpopup window gets invisible for little time & again it comes visible as i used code in checkchanged event of selectall checkbox as follows:

```
ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
```

But i want to keep modalpopup window as it is once checkbox for selectall is checked, dont want to disappears popup window & display again.
I used C# & asp.net.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to go back to serve side and select all check boxes from there. Do it from client side script and remove auto AutoPostBack true property from select all check box.

below link help you to write jQuery script.

[Check/Uncheck all Items in an ASP.NET CheckBox List using jQuery](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=236)

Comment: I tried this code but its not working, when i check selectall checkbox all items not gets checked. script is not working